# MYSQL GROUP_CONCAT multiple IDs and names (Multiple comment rows on multiple posts rows)

Tags: mysql, group-concat

I have 3 MYSQL tables:

**Posts**

```
post_id     post_name      post_date

   1        Hello          2013-04-23
   2        Goodbye        2013-04-24
```

**Users**

```
user_id   user_name

   1      Danny
   2      Max
```

**Comments**

```
comment_id   user_id     post_id     comment_text      comment_date

   1           1             1       Really good       2013-04-23
   2           2             2       Really bad        2013-04-24
   3           2             2       Just joking       2013-04-24
```

My goal is to display multiple post rows, with multiple comments ( which have been con-catted with the user_id, user_name & comment_text & separated with delimiters ).

Something like this:

**Result**

```
Post id     Post name    Comments

   1        Hello        1,Danny,Really good
   1        Goodbye      2,Max,Really bad|2,Max,Just joking
```

I've been scratching my head an searching for examples of this for hours. Any help with the MYSQL query would be much appreciated! Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use CONCAT within GROUP_CONCAT

Something like this:-

```
SELECT a.post_id, a.post_name, GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT_WS(",", c.user_id, c.user_name, b.comment_text) SEPARATOR "|")
FROM Posts a
INNER JOIN Comments b ON a.post_id = b.post_id
INNER JOIN Users c ON b.user_id = c.user_id
GROUP BY a.post_id, a.post_name
```